# Django Parametrize Test

Tags: django, pytest

I have a simple model factory:

```py
class SubjectFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = Subject

    title = 'Mathematics'
    slug = 'mathematics'
```

When I want to test the instance creation, my parametrization does not override default title and slug. It remains Mathematics. If I remove the line, I get an AttributeError:

```
AttributeError: type object 'SubjectFactory' has no attribute 'title'
```

Here is the instance test:

```py
import pytest
from courses.models import Subject

@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    'title, slug, validity', 
    [
        ('Algebra', 'algebra', True),
        ('', '', False),
    ],
)

def test_subject_instance(db, subject_factory, title, slug, validity):

    test = subject_factory(
        title=title,
        slug=slug
    )

    item = Subject.objects.all().count()
    assert item == validity
```

How can I run the test with these custom params?